# is Tcl_CancelEval declaration broken in TCL 8.6.4?

Tags: tcl

In the TCL 8.6.4 distribution the declaration for CancelEval in tclDecl.h is

```
int Tcl_CancelEval(Tcl_Interp *, Tcl_Obj *, ClientData, int);
```

but the documentation says the declaration is

```
int Tcl_CancelEval(Tcl_Interp *, ClientData, int);
```

In my code the first generates a segmentation violation.  I am now using a workaround to use the second, with the second arg = 0.  Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for asking this here. Documentation bugs like this are things we try to avoid…

Comment: tclDecls.h is itself compiled from another file, tcl.decls, which declares Tcl_CancelEval like this: `int Tcl_CancelEval(Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Obj *resultObjPtr, ClientData clientData, int flags)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear! The documentation is wrong, and has been since at least 2010. I could probe further back, but I'm guessing that the docs and the code never matched; it's just as wrong in all other 8.6 releases to date. We try very hard to not make these sorts of mistakes but they sometimes sneak through. This has now been fixed; it will form part of the next release (and next documentation build put online, which tends to be synchronised with releases).

Using 0 (or `NULL`) for the second argument is indeed acceptable; it makes the system use the default error message. If you had used a non-NULL argument, it would have been the error message to use, and would have had its reference count decremented in the process (which is unusual API behaviour, so worth noting).